# undefined reference to `sqrt'

Tags: c, nan, sqrt

Part of my program is to calculate `sqrt` of float number.
When I write `sqrt(1.0f);` I success to compile the program,but when I write `sqrt(-1.0f);`
the compilation fails with `undefined reference to 'sqrt'` - I suppose that in this case the `nan` value will be returned...
I compile the program uing gcc.
When I compile it with visual studio it is compiled successfuly with negative argument to sqrt.
How the problem could be solved
Thank you

Comment: gcc myprog.c -o myprog -lm   the -l to include a library m for the math library -lm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `-lm` flag on most Unix-based systems, as in:

Compile using:

```
gcc -c file.c
```

and then link using:

```
gcc -o program file.o -lm
```

Or if you don't want to separate the two compilation steps, simply write:

```
gcc -o program file.c -lm
```

Answer (score 4):

Link with `-lm` to link with the math library

Comment: Can you please give a reason for it. I tried including <math.h> in headers, but then facing the error as mentioned in the question.