# sqrt() function link error

Tags: c, sqrt

The following code is throwing undefined symbol error on Linux.

```
$ cat rms.c
/* sqrt example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  double param, result;
  param = 1024.0;
  result = sqrt (param);
  printf ("sqrt(%lf) = %lf\n", param, result );
  return 0;
}


$ gcc rms.c
/tmp/ccaWecFP.o(.text+0x24): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If  I replace argument to sqrt() with (double)16 then program is compiling and executing. Why is this throwing error in first case.

Comment: For sqrt() you need to reference the math library --- add -lm to the gcc command line

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I'm voting as "not a duplicate" because the "why *does* this work with a constant" is not answered over there.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780603/undefined-reference-to-sqrt

Answer (score 4):

This is a  linker error.

The linker is missing the implementation of `sqrt()`. It resides in the library `libm`.

Tell GCC to add it by applying the option `-lm`.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `sqrt()` is available in the **math library** or `libm`.

You have to **link** your program to the math library, as:

```
gcc rms.c -lm
```

A natural question is, how am I supposed to know this? The answer is in the manpages. If I do "man sqrt", I see the following. Note that **the linking instruction is provided in the synopsis**.

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <math.h>

       double sqrt(double x);

       Link with -lm.
```

Comment: Then why is that the program getting compiled and linked if a literal is given to sqrt() as argument, even though Im not linking with libm ?

Comment: It compiled successfully since `math.h` was duly included. But, based on the error message reported ("undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1"), I do not think the linking succeeded.

Comment: With literal as argument to sqrt() it got compiled, linked and executed too !

Answer (score 2):

You must link with `libm`

```
gcc rms.c -lm
```

If you want more explanation [Linking with external libraries](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html).

Good Luck ;)

Comment: Then why is that the program getting compiled and linked if a literal is given to sqrt() as argument, even though Im not linking with libm ?

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers say, you need to pass `-lm` in order to link to the library containing the `sqrt` symbol.

The reason it works with a constant argument is because `sqrt` is allowed to be implemented as a builtin. When GCC sees a builtin function called with constant arguments, it can calculate the result at compile-time instead of emitting a call to the external function in the library.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here discuss the linking error; I'm going to add an answer about why the result is correct if you replace `param` with a constant.

GCC has an optimization where it replaces functions with builtin equivalents (such as `sqrt`) and constant arguments (such as `16.0`) with the results of those calculations (such as `4.0`).

This is a form of constant folding.